# Python auto-detect and split regex groups

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex pattern which is too long to type it here, but you can read it from here:

https://linksnappy.com/api/REGEX

I want to re.compile it straight away, but I am getting AssertionError and inability to compile more than 100 named groups.

I tried writing a pattern to split the above one, but it's way too difficult to make it work and not raise any exceptions from sre_*.py.

Is there a function which can automatically split capture groups/alternatives, similar to sre_parse, but make a list with the regex alternatives from the above pattern?

Comment: I doubt this regex will do the job: it has `[^( |"|>|<|\r\n\|\n|$)]+` which is a clear user error (a grouping construct inside a negated character class). Also, you may quickly shorten the pattern by replacing `(http|https)` with `https?`

Comment: Exactly, I noticed these errors and points where the regex pattern can easily be shortened.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the strings and compiled it in python3, but did not get AssertionError. The only skill I employed is to use the literal string '''regex'''.

I also pasted it in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9hoKLX/1). It is also valid and gives very detailed explanations of all alternatives and capturing groups.

For python2, I did saw in the [source code](https://github.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/blob/master/Lib/sre_compile.py) that the number of capturing groups is limited to 100. In this case, python3 is the best option. If python2 is required, you may have to separate/shorten the regular expressions or choose not to use it.

> In the particular example you provided, you can change your regex into 5 independent ones **because it consists of 127 alternatives**. It has the pattern of (a|b|c|d|e|...), but each alternative contains capturing groups as well. Check the regex explanation link [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9hoKLX/1). Just make sure each regex has less than 100 capturing groups.

I hope it helps you solve the problem.

Comment: I am getting AssertionError on Ubuntu 18.04, default 2.7.15 packages. The software I am writing has to be cross-platform so I have to ensure it works everywhere.

Comment: No, it does not answer my question. I asked if there is a snippet or a function that can do that in code, not something in the regex101 website. I eventually requested from the developers of the above-mentioned website to return a json encoded object with regexes as an array.